# Can't write local files in Flash Player 10+ online (but works when used locally)

Tags: flash, savefiledialog, filereference

I am trying to write a local file with Flash Player 10+ using the FileReference class, following the format from this blog post by Mike Chambers: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/

Essentially the code is this:

```
private function onSaveButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void{      
    fr = new FileReference();
    fr.save(fileToSave);}
```

It works fine locally on my machine but when used online, it doesn't bring up the save file dialogue when the save button is clicked.  I assume this is some sort of permissions or security related issue?

Comment: Do you have an example running on a server? There's nothing that I know of that restricts FileReference.save when executing from a server, so a running example would be helpful.

Comment: It works when I run it on a localhost server but not on my online server

Comment: What is `fileToSave`? Do `onFileSave`, `onCancel` or `onSaveError` trace anything

Comment: @Eugeny89 I debugged it more and it looks like its actually a crossdomain flash security issue related to getting an image from S3 to create a bitmap out of.  I've created a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217973/flash-flex-crossdomain-issue-using-bitmapdata-draw-for-image-from-aws-s3-res

Answer (score 1):

You should check your log for `SecurityError`s. A sandbox violation is nearly always the cause when IO works locally but not online.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance of *FileReference* might be garbage collected. Same happens with file upload.

Try to move it to instance variable:

```
private var fr = new FileReference();
private function onSaveButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void{      

    fr.save(fileToSave);
}
```